# SWReveal View Controller (IOS App development)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` to show front and rear view. Inside rear view I am using full view Mode and insert table view, but table view cell content is not lies in the middle of screen. it little swap to the right side. I have tried almost every thing, from storyBoard I have used Auto layout and inside cell.m file inside layout subview class but no result.

But when I tap on cell content it appears in the middle of screen, As I wish. please suggest me so if this screen load content appears in the middle of screen of tableview. Your suggestion is highly appreciated. enter image description here

[[image: 1]

you can see how weird it looks

Comment: Now showing please check now

Answer (score 0):

Now I got the answer, we can edit the sw reveal rear width to screen size and same applied to table view size, In this way we can bring the content of tableview in the middle of view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypnxl.png)